# Amazon SNS push notification - redirect to web url after clicking on push

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Some mobile marketing platforms allow to setup behavior what should happen when user clicks on push notification: either opening app, deep linking into app, or redirecting to any web url (link that will be provided in push notification).

Does SNS push notification supports these behavior types of clicking on received push, or only opening app and nothing more? 
I can’t find any info about that in AWS docs / forum. 
In case if it’s possible, please provide links to docs and description of how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, for that of now, deep links can't be sent via SNS. Amazon's service title itself provides the name of "Simple Notification Service". We can simply send the notification and in the run time also we can't select the specific set of users to send the push notifications. If you want to send the push notification to multiple users, you have to create the topic and have to add endpoints there, after that we can send the push via topic.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the same notification payload (with deep link metadata) I got from Pinpoint with [SNS platform-specific payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html).

Also, you can explore custom data and more possibilities for your push notifications here:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref